# django haystack indexes nothing

Tags: python, django, tomcat, solr

I am using Ubuntu 13 and Django 1.4.5, I have installed solr, tomcat6, (sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat) djangohaystack etc. and they seem work fine. but i cannot make the index.

search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes, site
from firms_api.models import Company

class CompanyNameIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Company

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.Company.company_name

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

site.register(Company, CompanyNameIndex)
```

the settings file:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'api'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'solr'
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'djangobb_index')
HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = "http://solrserver.com/solr"
```

than I did:

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema -f schema.xml
sudo mv schema.xml /etc/solr/conf/schema.xml 
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                                                                [ OK ] 
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat6                                                                                                [ OK ] 

python manage.py rebuild_index
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.

python manage.py haystack_info
Loaded URLconf to initialize SearchSite...
Main site registered 0 index(es).
```

when i attempt to make a search on solr i got this error:

```
HTTP Status 400 - no field name specified in query and no defaultSearchField defined in schema.xml

type Status report

message no field name specified in query and no defaultSearchField defined in schema.xml

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (no field name specified in query and no defaultSearchField defined in schema.xml).
```

anyone has any idea where do i make the mistake?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have installed haystack 2.0.0 beta and it works now.